# Monitor : no image after turning off then on

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, monitor

I would like to use my monitor as display for two computers, so I would like to switch the input as I want beetween the computer 1 and the computer 2.
When I switch on the computer 2 everything is fine but when I return on the first computer this one don't display anything and the monitor display "no signal on {name of input}".

There is the same phenomenom when I turn off then turn on the screen : no signal. I don't know what to do to fix this.

I run on xubuntu 14.04 with nvidia proprietary drivers.